# Azure pipelines template - toLower on a parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build template used by several pipelines, and I need to simply transform a parameter using toLower.

toLower is documented here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#tolower

this is my last attempt:

`parameters:
  imageName: '$(Build.Repository.Name)'
  lcImageName: "$[toLower(parameters.imageName)]" #this is my current attempt`

later on, on a Bash@3 step, I'm trying to use the value with

`args: 'omitted/${{ parameters.lcImageName }}:$(output.dockertag)'`

but I can see the value is not expanded

I also tried to directly call that toLower where I needed it, no expansion neither.

I just need to transform a param using toLower and use it in a specific step, I'm a bit surprised I'm asking this here .

Comment: Please note that there is a `lower` function in Azure DevOps Pipelines now: see [my new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68369190/1542187) for more detail.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No need for any workarounds! There **is** a `lower` function in Azure DevOps Pipelines (not `toLower`):

> **lower**
>
> - Converts a string or variable value to all lowercase characters
> - Min parameters: 1. Max parameters 1
> - Returns the lowercase equivalent of a string
> - Example: lower('FOO') returns foo
>
> ~[from MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#lower)

### Example

❗ Please note that the first example below uses **compile time evaluation**. Thanks @marc-stevenson for pointing this out in the comments (as well as sharing [the link to learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops))!

```yaml
# using compile-time evaluation
parameters:
- name: someString
  type: string
  default: "HELLO"    

variables:
   A: ${{ lower(parameters.someString) }}

steps:
  - script: echo $A # outputs hello
```

```yaml
# using run-time evaluation
parameters:
- name: someString
  type: string
  default: "HELLO"    

variables:
   A: $[ lower(parameters.someString) ]

steps:
  - script: echo $A # outputs hello
```

Comment: sweet! works like a charm - this needs to be the accepted answer!

Comment: Note that ${{ <expression> }} is a compile time evaluation whereas $[ <expression> ] will give you a runtime evaluation. Compile time is fine for static values whereas you'll want to use runtime for more dynamic values. Refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 4):

here's an example of doing what the existing answer suggests (I dont think there is any other way of doing this except for using a script):

```
  - bash: |
      ${{ format('imageName=$(echo "{0}" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=imageName]$imageName"',
          parameters.solutionName ) }} 
    displayName: Image Lowercase
```

EDIT:

this is now supported via `lower()` command:

```
Example: lower('FOO') returns foo
```

Comment: ended up doing a similar thing on my own,`LCIM=$(echo "${{ parameters.imageName }}" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]); echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=lcImageName]$LCIM"`

Comment: Thanks for this. I took it a further step and removed dashes as well:

`- bash: |
            ${{ format('k8snamespace=$(echo "{0}" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" | tr -d "-")
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=k8snamespace]$k8snamespace"',
                parameters.k8sNamespaceForPR ) }}`

Comment: Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68369190/1542187)- there *is* a built in way to format strings to their lowercase version now.

Answer (score 0):

You linked to Azure Resource Manager documentation, which is for ARM templates that are used for provisioning Azure Resources.

But your syntax looks like you are trying to use the function in a YAML pipeline in Azure DevOps?

Afaik, there is no "toLower" function available in Azure DevOps Pipelines.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#functions

The built-in functions all use ordinal ignore-case comparisons.

If you have to have a lowercase lcImageName value, create a powershell task that takes imageName as a parameter and performs a lowercase operation on it, and assign that return value to a new pipeline variable.

Comment: ‍♂️- I was reading the wrong doc. It makes sense it doesn't work now.
Thanks for the suggestion, will do it.

Comment: There is now a lower function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#lower